# can LD_PRELOAD trick considered as a type of instrumentation?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, mpi, profiler, instrumentation

If you set `LD_PRELOAD` to the path of a shared object, that file will be loaded **before** any other library (including the C runtime, `libc.so`). This trick is used by a number of profilers, especially MPI profilers. My question is, can this pre-loading be considered as a type of instrumentation? If yes, will it be source level instrumentation or static binary instrumentation?

Comment: there's got to be more to this question.  what are you trying to determine?

Comment: I am trying to classify various profilers. Hence my question, can this library pre-loading be considered as instrumentation?